# Swap Background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently finishing off a jQuery slide that enables the user to click a div and then a div slides down. But what I wish to do is to change the background image of div.slide while it's down, so I have an up arrow and then a down arrow for each state.

I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $(".tst").slideToggle( 'slow', function(){ });
      });
</script>
```

So far I have what's above and feel like I'm not too far away from the rest, but I cannot seem to work out how to change the background?

**New Edit of code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tst').hide();
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $("div.slide").css('background-image', 'url("http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/upward_arrow.jpg")');
         $(".tst").slideToggle( 'slow', function(){
         });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML and a JSFiddle as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using jQuery's `.css()` method which allows to change any css attribute of an object. Otherwise, you can try using to different classes (f.e. `.bg1` and `.bg2`) and change them with `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()` or `toggleClass()`.

It may be a good idea to wait until the object has faded out to change the background, so use the following:

**With `.css()`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $(".tst").slideToggle( 'slow', function(){
             $(this).css('background-image',...)
         });
      });
</script>
```

**With [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

First we need the two classes (or subclasses):

```
div.slide.up_arrow{
    background-image: url("http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/upward_arrow.jpg");
}
div.slide.down_arrow{
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

We should first add one of them and then toggle for each click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tst').hide();
    $("div.slide").addClass('up_arrow')
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $("div.slide").toggleClass('up_arrow').toggleClass('down_arrow');
         $(".tst").slideToggle( 'slow', function(){
         });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: this is great and has actually helped me so much! But how I would I use the toggle class as I am having some issues with the background image.

I have edited my question to show my new example of code.

Comment: I've edited the answer with your new question :)
Remember to look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Fantastic! Well explained, understood and now get it. Didn't have to supply the code but it's extremely appreciated. Thank you Sikian.

Comment: You're welcome :)
Btw, take this little cheatsheet which may be of help if you're going to work with jQuery: http://oscarotero.com/jquery/